# Using a CSV as a datasource for a datagridview in c#

Tags: c#, csv, datagridview, datatable

I have a CSV file that I want to be my data source for a datagridview, but before the column headers there are 3 random lines, which are not needed and affect the table

For example:

```
Username: 01   
Date: 04/02/13   
*blank*            
Source, file, date, time
```

The code I am using to get the CSV and use it as the datagridview:

```
{
   string conStr = @"Driver={Microsoft Text Driver (*.txt; *.csv)};Dbq=" + Path.GetDirectoryName(Path.GetFullPath(path)) + ";Extensions=csv,txt";
   OdbcConnection conn = new OdbcConnection(conStr);

   OdbcDataAdapter da = new OdbcDataAdapter("Select * from [" + Path.GetFileName(path) + "]", conn);
   DataTable dt = new DataTable(path);
   da.Fill(dt);

   dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;

   da.Dispose();
   conn.Close();
   conn.Dispose();
}
```

So basically, I need to read all the CSV for the table, but delete the first 3 lines of the text. Is there a way to do this as a query?

Comment: You mentioned column headers so dt.Rows.RemoveAt(index) will not work for you. You have to read this file delete first 3 lines and save it as a new file (if you have permissions) and then read data from the new file.

Comment: That's right Kashif, removing the rows would work were it not for the column headers on the 4th line

Answer (score 2):

You could use [.NET txtReader for Text files](http://www.xporttools.net/txtReader.aspx)

It supports the following connectionstring options that might come in handy for you

- Skip Rows
- Has Header
- Ignore Empty Lines

Here is an example connection string:

```
 Data Source='C:\MyFolder';Delimiter=',';Has Quotes=True;Skip Rows=0;Has Header=True;
 Comment Prefix='';Column Type=String,String,String,Int32,Boolean,String,String;
 Trim Spaces=False;Ignore Empty Lines=True;
```

Answer (score 0):

Insert the following lines after you fill the datatable and before you assign it to your gridview's datasource:

```
 dt.Rows[0].Delete();
 dt.Rows[1].Delete();
 dt.Rows[2].Delete();
 dt.AcceptChanges();
```

Comment: What about the column names of data table?

Comment: That would work for getting rid of the unwanted lines, but the column names of the table are on the 4th line, and then the rows deleted doesn't solve the problem of the column headers. Unless they are added manually before hand?